# OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a function that performs a search like

```
def search(cls: Type[T], session, search_query):
        combined_search_vector = (
            x.y.search_vector
            | sa.func.coalesce(xClass.yClass.search_vector, "")
        )

        with session as ctx_session:
            query = (
                ctx_session.query(Class)
                .join(xClass.YClass)
                .filter(combined_search_vector.match(f"'{search_query}'"))
            )

        return query
```

Initially I had the search function writen like bellow, is possible that the idle transaction error came from this?

```
 @classmethod
    def search(cls: Type[T], session, search_query):
        combined_search_vector = (
            x.y.search_vector
            | sa.func.coalesce(xClass.yClass.search_vector, "")
        )

        try:
            query = (
                ctx_session.query(Class)
                .join(xClass.YClass)
                .filter(combined_search_vector.match(f"'{search_query}'"))
            )

        except sa_exc.DatabaseError:
            session.rollback()

        return query
```

The search functionality works fine but this function throws a lot of

```
 OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
```

In my knowledge `postgres` should be handling the sessions here. What am I missing?

This is my set up at the top

```
     sessionmaker = attr.ib(default=None, repr=False)
    _session = attr.ib(default=None, repr=False)
    _engine = attr.ib(repr=False)
    _search_index_prefix = "search_"

    @_engine.default
    def create_engine(self):
        url = self.config["core"]["url"]
        engine = create_engine(url, echo=False)
        self._sessionmaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        return engine

    @property
    def session(self):
        if self._session is None:
            self._session = self._sessionmaker()
            self._session.execute("SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.2;")
        return self._session

    def close(self):
        if self._session is not None:
            self._session.close()
            self._session = None
```

Also is there a way for me to for connection to go idle on my development machine for testing purposes?

Comment: The context manager will automatically close the session on exit, so its connection will be rolled back.  Are you certain this code is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes I am certain @snakecharmerb, I initially didn't handle sessions well. I  have updated the question to include previous code snippet. Could the idle transactions be from that previous deployment?